# Android Studio Flutter Project Error: Out of Memory

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I run any flutter project on Android Studio and it throws an Out Of Memory Error.
The message shown in the console looks something like this:

```java
e:\b\build\slave\windows_engine\build\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\scavenger.cc: 411: error: Out of memory.
Dumping native stack trace for thread 2750
  [0x00007ff676324b63] Dart_IsPrecompiledRuntime
  [0x00007ff676324b63] Dart_IsPrecompiledRuntime
-- End of DumpStackTrace
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Tuns out i had to `flutter clean`, clear Android studio caches. And restart the computer (of course :D).

Answer (score 7):

A few things you can try:

1. Run `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade` in the terminal
2. Uninstall and reinstall the app
3. (Android Studio) File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart
4. Restart your computer

Answer (score 1):

Considering the lack of information you've provided, I can only consider the fact that the good practice for creating mobile applications, judging by the fact that a mobile device's memory is usually lower( and the memory allocation is much slower ), when compared to a computer's memory and memory allocation speed, is to store your information in a database and access the needed information using queries. 
That could actually fix your issue. If not, please provide more information.

Comment: Instead I moved the entire SDK folder into a different disk. The issue is fixed now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

shutdown computer completely, don't to hibernate.
That works for me.
You can shutdown computer completely using this command

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I restarted my PC and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just close emulator by task manager. emulator must fully restart