# Out of memory, flutter stream

Tags: flutter

the below stream method is triggered every frame

```
stream() async {
_isStreaming=true;
var counter=0;
channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://192.168.11.8:8000/real-time/')
) as IOWebSocketChannel?;
_cameraController?.startImageStream((CameraImage img)  async{
  final imageBytes= await convertYUV420toImageColor(img);

  if(_isStreaming) {
    channel?.sink.add(imageBytes);
  }
});

channel?.stream.listen((message) {
  print(message);

  var jsonDecodex = jsonDecode(message);

  var prediction = jsonDecodex['prediction'];
  var predictProba = jsonDecodex['predict_proba'];

  _prediction = prediction;
  _accuracy =predictProba+"%";
  if(mounted) {
    setState(() {});
  }
},
);}
```

I'm working on a flutter app that opens a stream and sends every frame to a Django server via WebSockets, However, nearly after 1 minute of streaming 'out of memory' error happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63017921/11675817

Comment: I know but I can't deal with it sorry for not mentioning this, ImageBytes is a converted image from YUV420 to RGB image in a Big(O^2) method.

Comment: @MKarimi didn't work out!

Comment: @pskink from 10kb to 15kb on the emulator camera, around 1MB on the mobile camera. the error is rising in both